# Modify / Rewrite single template url structure

Tags: categories, url-rewriting, urls, single

Is it possible to add the post category name to the the WordPress single template url structure if i am not using category pages to build the site menu?

from

www.domain.com/single-post-title

to

www.domain.com/category-name/post-title

I am using a custom page template that is loading posts from a specific category.

Would I have to edit the urls in the .htaccess file, or is it possible to do this using WP_Rewrite?

Comment: Since posts can have multiple categories, how are you to select which one is used?

Comment: in this scenario, posts wont have the need to have multiple cats, just the one